# How to use code repo so that same user from multiple PCs can access it in Netbeans IDE

Tags: git, netbeans, mercurial, code

I am planning to work on a software project using Netbeans-- now I want to work across multiple PCs - how can I set up Netbeans and the Git/Mercurial repo so that I can for eg-- make code changes in one pc, commit to code repo, and then when I go to second pc i can see the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans.org has a great tutorial on setting up the git repository on your machine. Simply replicate the process across your PCs and git will take care of the versioning and history.
(https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html)